# Why is FindStr returning not-found

Tags: batch-file

`%vData%` equals the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path` variable which includes `;%main%\Programs\Go\Bin`.
`%main%` is a variable in the same Environment which holds the value `C:\Main`.

I want to check if this value exists before adding, so I have the code:

```
echo %vData% | FindStr /L /I /C:"%%main%%\\Programs\\Go\\Bin"
```

I have tried `%%main%%` and `%main%` and `%^main%` and `%^^main%` but it consistently tells me the string does not exist.

How do I get it to show me it does exist?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the variable really contains the literal string `;%main%\Programs\Go\Bin` (you can prove it by simply doing `echo/%vData%`), I believe that you are looking for this:

```
echo/%%vData%%| findstr /I /C:"%%main%%\\Programs\\Go\\Bin"
```

or, even better, since special characters in `vData` become protected:

```
cmd /V /C echo(!vData!| findstr /I /C:"%%main%%\\Programs\\Go\\Bin"
```

---

The problem with your code:

```
echo %vData% | FindStr /L /I /C:"%%main%%\\Programs\\Go\\Bin"
```

is the fact that <s>either side of the pipe `|` is executed in a new `cmd` instance</s> *the left side of the pipe `|` is executed in a new `cmd` instance since it is an internal command [updated due to the finding handled in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57486365)]*, so variable `vData` is expanded twice:

1. when the whole command line is executed, the left side becomes:

   ```
   echo ...;%main%\Programs\Go\Bin
   ```
2. when the left side of the pipe is executed, it becomes:

   ```
   echo ...;C:\Main\Programs\Go\Bin
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This routine should assist.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "main=VALUE OF MAIN"
SET "vdata=something;%%main%%\Programs\Go\Binsomethingelse"
ECHO -----
ECHO %vdata%
SET vdata
ECHO -----

SET vData| FindStr /L /I /C:"%%main%%\\Programs\\Go\\Bin"
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
ECHO -----

SET vData|FINDSTR /b /L /i "vdata=" | FindStr /L /I /C:"%%main%%\\Programs\\Go\\Bin"
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
ECHO -----

echo %vData% | FindStr /L /I /C:"%%main%%\\Programs\\Go\\Bin"
ECHO %errorlevel%

GOTO :EOF
```

Note the filter `/b /L /i "vdata="` which protects the routine from the presence of other variables starting `vdata` like `vdata2` or whatever. If you have but 1, this extra filter is not required.