# In Windows Batch, why a for loop surrounded by parenthesis won't expand a variable it's told to echo?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, parentheses

In my project, I need to parse a multiline output from a command with `findstr`. To do so, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31046373/12194725) to create an array of lines and `echo` them one by one using a `for` loop:

```cmd
(for /L %n in (1 1 %info_count%) do echo %info[%n]%)| findstr /R /C:"[0-9s]: [0-9]" /C:"bytes"
```

The problem is this leads to the `echo` part outputting `%info[1]%`, `%info[2]%` and so on.

Removing the first set of parenthesis, however, leads to the `do` part of the `for` loop interpreting both the `echo` and the piped part, which means that instead of six `echo` outputs through one pipe, I get six (expanded) `echo` outputs through six different pipes.

What is causing this issue?

PS: the snippet above is just what I used to investigate in the resulting prompt after my whole script has run. In the main project, naturally I'm using delayed expansion for my variables and proper variables inside loops for batch files (i.e. `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, `!var!` and `%%a`

---

**Edit:** in light of [jeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67832024/12194725), I'm adding a longer snippet, as well as my understanding that the problem lies in `findstr` being an external exe.

```cmd
for /f %%d in ('^(for /L %%n in ^(1 1 !info_count!^) do echo !info[%%n]!^)^| ^(findstr /R /C:"[0-9s]: [0-9]" /C:"bytes"^)^| find /c /v ""') do (
    if [%%d]==[0] (
        ...
    ) else (
        ...
```

It's aim is to analyze the output of `mkvmerge -i`, a multiline text that has been put in an array (`!info1!`, `!info2` etc), use `findstr` to detect one of two desired matches and then use `find` to output the number of matches, which will dictate the behavior in the next lines.

What I'm trying to achieve with all of this is to avoid launching mkvmerge multiple times, but I already had a working alternative that simply called mkvmerge again instead of the `for /l` loop (which means the double piping was working in another scenario).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57492041/12194725), which I found thanks to [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb), suggests adding the parentheses around `findstr` would solve the problem. That was not the case for me.

Comment: You have to use double % in the variable controlled by the FOR: `FOR /L %%n (....)` Otherwise `%n` gets replaced itself, with ... nothing.

Comment: @user207421 The command is executed on the command line, therefore the signle percent sign is correct

Answer (score 1):

Testing this on the command line isn't useful, because the behavior differs from batch files.

The main problem here is the percent expansion. It's expanded while a block is parsed!

The next problem is that nesting of percent expressions can't be done this way.
`%info[%n]%` is splitted into `%info[%` and `n]%`.

In a batch file you would use delayed expansion to avoid all this problems.

```
(for /L %%n in (1 1 !info_count!) do echo !info[%%n]!) | findstr /R /C:"[0-9s]: [0-9]" /C:"bytes"
```

But it still fails, because you are piping a block with delayed expansion to `findstr`.
Piping starts two child cmd.exe processes with the default configuration and then the delayed expansion is disabled again.
[Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/463115)

You could move the findstr into the block, then the `!info[%%n]!` will be expanded before it's transferred to the new cmd.exe instance.

```
for /L %%n in (1 1 !info_count!) do (
  echo !info[%%n]! | findstr /R /C:"[0-9s]: [0-9]" /C:"bytes"
)
```

This will be slower, because it starts findstr and the pipe for each loop.

**After your additional informations:**

Bracketing `findstr` doesn't help here, because that's not your problem.
If you start `findstr` directly or within a cmd.exe instance doesn't change the behavior, that trick is only necessary when there are percent expansions in the piped `findstr` part.

If you only want to count the matches, that can be done without `find`.

```
set /a match_cnt=0
for /L %%n in (1 1 %info_count%) do (
  echo !info[%%n]! | findstr /R /C:"[0-9s]: [0-9]" /C:"bytes" > nul
  if !errorlevel! == 0 set /a match_cnt+=1
)

echo matches: !match_cnt!
```

You could also modify your initial code to work with:

```
( 
    for /L %%n in (1 1 %info_count%) do @(
        cmd /V:on /C echo !info[%%n]!
    )
) | findstr /R /C:"[0-9s]: [0-9]" /C:"bytes"
```

Or the same without the (slow) invocation of `cmd /v:on`

```
    call echo %%^^info[%%n]%%
```

Comment: First of all I don't think `%info[%n]% is being split, as my testing shows `%n%` expanded. Second, moving `findstr` into the block bumps into another problem, I'll have to edit my question and use a bigger snippet to show why. Third, the line of investigation you presented lead me to believing `findstr` being an external exe is the problem. Nevertheless, the solution offered, bracketing it, didn't help. All of this has been very helpful, I'll continue investigating tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: @FabioFreitas You could test the split behavior by using `set info[=WRONG split` before